# fgets breaks glibc hash table in C

Tags: c, hashtable, glibc, fgets

```
#include <search.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HASHT_SIZE 2000000
#define N 1000000
char *keys[N];
int keySize;

int main() {
    ENTRY e, *ep;
    hcreate(HASHT_SIZE);
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("./map.txt", "r");
    char line[500], *li;
    double dub;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)) {
        e.key = line;
        if (hsearch(e, FIND) == NULL) {
            e.data = (void *)keySize;
            li = malloc(strlen(e.key) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(li, line);
            ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
            keys[keySize++] = li;
            if (ep == NULL) {
                printf("failure");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that lookups via `hsearch(e,FIND)` are returning `NULL` as soon as the next `while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),f))` is run. Why is that? Why does `hsearch(keys[0],FIND)` fail as soon as this `fgets` is called? How is the hash table forgetting the entry when `fgets` is called?

Comment: One bug here: `li=malloc(strlen(e.key)*sizeof(char));` - should be: `li=malloc(strlen(e.key)+1);`

Comment: You have forgotten that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* need space too. Since you don't allocate enough memory you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when `strcpy` writes out of bounds of your allocated memory.

Comment: You made a copy of the string with `malloc` and `strcpy`, but you forgot to update `e.key` to point to that string.

Comment: You should check the return value of `malloc`, although that is unlikely to be the cause of the problem in this case.

Comment: I changed my code to add space for the null character for the malloc call but my problem is still there. As soon as I break out of this while loop, hsearch(keys[0],FIND) is returning null when I have verified that in the while loop it wasn't null.

Comment: As pointed out by @user3386109, you should set `e.key=li;` before `ep=hsearch(e,ENTER);` because `hsearch` does not make a copy of the key string and you overwrite `line` for each entry.

Comment: @user3386109 even though e.key is already set to equal to line at this point and I'm literally copying that string via strcpy(li,line) updating the e.key to equal li for some reason fixed the problem. How is an assignment and strcpy different? Why would a second assignment of li be needed?

Comment: @IanAbbott but e.key=line is set beforehand. You're right that e.key=li fixes it but I don't understand why. e.key is reset to line on each entry in the while loop.

Comment: `e.key` is just a pointer. So if you `hsearch(e, ENTER)` when `e.key` points to `line`, then every entry in the hash table points to `line`, and every entry in the hash table is the last string read by `fgets`.

Comment: You probably also want to [remove the newline that `fgets` puts in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776). Right now, all of the hash table keys have a newline at the end.

Comment: `hsearch(e, ENTER)` copies `e` into the hash table, but it does not make a copy of the string pointed to by `e.key`. You have `e.key` set to `line`, so when you call `fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)` again, you are overwriting the buffer for the key that is already in the hash table. So the old key will no longer match its hash code and a subsequent `hsearch(e,FIND)` for that key will fail. Also, as pointed out by @user3386109, you may want to remove the newline characters from the key before calling `hsearch` unless you want the newline to be part of the key.

Comment: @IanAbbott That makes a lot of sense. I agree with everything you said

Comment: You haven't initialized `keySize` anywhere.

Comment: @user3386109 you're right about everything. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @lurker it's a global variable initialized to 0 and the casting is allowed.